# MSSQL ODBC PHP non-English character issue with "like" query

Tags: php, .net, sql-server, odbc

I am working on a project with PHP and MSSQL Server. The connection with database is made with ODBC. Initially I have issue with fetching the data for Non-English characters. It was displaying "???" instead of proper Greek/German letters. But it is resolved.

Now I want to fetch a simple record with field name "lastname" for any record in any language. It is working properly for English language but not for others.

When I debugged query on SQL server then I came to know that my query is generating in this format:

1. For English:

   ```
   select * from tablename where lastname like N'%abc%'
   ```

   Which displays result properly.
2. But for non-English language:

   ```
   select * from tablename where lastname like N'%Î¼Î±Î¸Î·Î¼Î±Ï„Î¹ÎºÎ¬%'
   ```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: most connections connect with a default character set, and this can also be set, I suspect you have a connection charset that does not support the other languages. mysqli_get_charset() &  mysqli_set_charset() are probably the commands you need.

Comment: Can you show part of your code? Thanks.

Comment: $qry = "SELECT *
  FROM tblPatients WHERE tblPatients.PatientName1 LIKE N'%".$patientName."%'";

$result =odbc_exec($this->conn,$qry);

If I pass $patientName in english its working fine but If the parameter string is in greek then it is not showing results. 

If I run same query in SQL studio its working. But while connecting via ODBC, the greek string value getting changed. I have debug this query and the query on runtime will look like - 

SELECT *
  FROM tblPatients WHERE  tblPatients.PatientName1 LIKE N'%Î¼Î±Î¸Î·Î¼Î±Ï„Î¹ÎºÎ¬%'; 
I hope you guys will help me. 
Thanks !

Comment: @Zhorov : Can you please guide me in this ?

Comment: You may try using parameterized query with odbc_prepare() and odbc_execute(). Then your WHERE clause will be something like this "WHERE tblPatients.PatientName1 LIKE N'%' + ? + '%'".

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Zhorov but its not working with prepare & execute. Still results are same.